# Unity Metal is not working on iOS 32 bin old iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

Since I changed color library rendering in my Unity 2017.1.2 game from gamma to linear, for IOS I had to use metal only (per unity requirement).
However this causes startup crash on older iPhone models (4S, 5, ..) that are 32 bit.
iOS: 8, 9 and 10
XCode: 7
Here is what debug window shows:

[image]

```
2017-12-20 22:54:34.835 RentoFortune[732:197101] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2017-12-20 22:54:34.842 RentoFortune[732:197101] Metal API Validation Disabled
2017-12-20 22:54:34.846 RentoFortune[732:197101] *** Assertion failure in -[UnityAppController renderingAPI], /Users/deyan/Documents/RentoFortuneHQ/Bin_4.6.2.1_dev/Classes/UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:138
2017-12-20 22:54:35.481 RentoFortune[732:197101] Uncaught exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException: [UnityAppController renderingAPI] called before [UnityAppController selectRenderingApi]
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x25af40ef <redacted> + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33f86c77 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x25af3fad <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x267f4bc9 <redacted> + 92
    4   RentoFortune                        0x000e7cbd -[UnityAppController(Rendering) renderingAPI] + 268
    5   RentoFortune                        0x000f988d -[UnityAppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 660
    6   UIKit                               0x291c0c85 <redacted> + 372
    7   UIKit                               0x293b726b <redacted> + 2442
    8   UIKit                               0x293b990f <redacted> + 1406
    9   UIKit                               0x293c45e9 <redacted> + 36
    10  UIKit                               0x293b80c7 <redacted> + 130
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x2c5c8ec1 <redacted> + 16
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x25aba035 <redacted> + 12
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x25ab92f9 <redacted> + 216
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x25ab7e53 <redacted> + 1714
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x25a036d1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x25a034e3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    17  UIKit                               0x291ba867 <redacted> + 558
    18  UIKit                               0x291b5445 UIApplicationMain + 1440
    19  RentoFortune                        0x000df78f main + 206
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x34554aaf <redacted> + 2
)
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

Comment: In your projects render settings, try switching to an earlier version of OpenGL. That could be the issue. Not sure though.

Comment: Thank you but I have to use metal. The whole project depends on it. OpenGLES is not an option..

Comment: It's worth mentioning both iOS version and your XCode version in your question. Also disable Metal API Validation in Xcode and see what happens. If already disabled, enable it and try again.

Comment: Thank you. I just added it. XCode 7, iOS 8, 9 and 10 (not 100% sure for 10)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but looking up compatibility, it seems like Metal support only started with the IPhone 5S. Link here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link. So it seems there is no solution for my question..